# Compensating for Feedback Capacitance

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, ac

I'm trying to build a two stage opamp inverting amplifier with a gain of ~90 @160kHz. The purpose of doing multi stage amplification is so I can have a high input impedance along with the first stage is used to drive a ADC for digital processing. The inverted signal is then used to drive a high voltage circuit. I've simulated the circuit using LtSpice and get the result I am expecting:

[image: ![enter image description here]
[image]
After testing the physical circuit I noticed that a large amount of feedback capacitance is present between the output of the second stage and input of the first stage (~100pF). This greatly reduced the gain that I am able to achieve as increasing the gain just causes the input signal to drop more and more.

Assuming the Opamps have the required gain width product and other parameters is there a possible feedback network that would compensate for the reduced gain due to capacitive feedback? Could this also be an issue with my layout that could cause such insane capacitive feedback? I was considering using coax to improve the isolation between input and output (close proximity on pcb). Is this a good direction to explore?

Layout [image]

Comment: How did you notice that capacitance - how much did it change the gain? Between what nodes precisely do you think this capacitance might reside? How did you conclude that a value of 100 pF might be the problem?

Comment: A bad layout can give you excessive node to node stray capacitance. It's not a good idea to try to 'compensate' this, far better to get your layout sanitary. Output next to input is not a good idea, at least not if they're out in the open. 100pF sounds wildly big for stray capacitance between random things that aren't intended to be capacitors, 10pF is more like the ballpark. If you're estimating this C by fitting behaviour with SPICE, then maybe you have something else unmodelled, I notice you've used the word 'assuming' in your question. Try running each stage by itself, and fit those.

Comment: @Andyaka I noticed removing C1 from the circuit improves the overall gain. After measuring with a multimeter (not super accurate) it gave a reading of around 200pF with C1 and 120pF without C1. I then tested in simulation where feedback capacitance starts to kill the gain and it is most prominent at 15pF+.

Comment: @Neil_UK The actual geometry of the circuit requires the input and output to be routed close together. I'll attach part of the layout to the question. I've tried each stage independently and they work well but combined the gain isn't what is calculated. I assume this is feedback capacitance.

Comment: If you remove C1 you remove the input signal so that makes no sense at at all. And what do you actually mean when you say this: *it gave a reading of around 200pF with C1 and 120pF without C1* - what is "it" you refer to? Please be super-clear and check what you write.

Comment: @Andyaka In the physical circuit V2 is already coupled through a capacitor to the input. I'll updated the ltspice model to reflect this for you. C1 is acting as purely filtering.

Comment: This is a system problem. You were the first to use the word 'insane', which a good description of the input and output of an amplifier that close together. I note it's overall an inverting amplifier, so any out to in capacitance will be magnified by the Miller effect. You need to rethink your PCB layout and move the I/O apart. If they must be that close together, then go to coaxial connectors, and screen the traces.

Comment: @MackenzieGoodwin I've easily achieved voltage gains in the area you want with a few BJTs, which can easily stand off 30 VDC, too, at the frequency you are discussing. An input impedance in the few hundred kOhm isn't hard, either. And I'm not sure why I see 2p and 5p caps at this frequency... this just suggests to me there's something very wrong with the design process. (I haven't tried to duplicate your results -- I've only quickly skimmed it for about a minute.)